# Java inheritance (method overriding and overloading)

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding

Besides that Java inheritance is a fundamental feature of the language, I have some questions.
Here is the source for my testing example:

```
class MyClass{

    public void say(String t){
        System.out.println("Hello MyClass "+t);
    }

    public void print(MyClass t){
        System.out.println("MyClass is printed");
    }

    public void anotherPrint(int i){
        System.out.println("MyClass is printed again");
    }
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass{

    public void say(String t){
        System.out.println("Hello MyClass2 "+t);
    }

    public void print(MyClass2 t){
        System.out.println("MyClass2 is printed");
    }

    public void anotherPrint(double i){
        System.out.println("MyClass2 is printed again");
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        MyClass klass = new MyClass2();

        klass.say("h"); //Question 1 (Prints: "Hello MyClass2 h")

        klass.print(new MyClass2()); //Question 2 (Prints: "MyClass is printed")
        klass.print(new MyClass()); //Question 3 (Prints: "MyClass is printed")

        klass.anotherPrint(1); //Question 4 (Prints: "MyClass is printed again")
        klass.anotherPrint(1.0); //Question 5 (Throws Exception!)
    }
}
```

**I have the following questions:**
1. The klass object is instance of `MyClass`. Why does it execute the method from the `MyClass2` class?
2,3 . At question 1 klass calls the method of the `MyClass2` class. Here I used a parameter that fits to each one of the overridden and overloaded (simultaneously) methods. Why klass object always calls the method from the `MyClass` class?
4. It is normal. No question at all.
5. It is right to throw an exception. The klass object does not have this method with double parameter. But, why it is not called the method from the `MyClass2` class, just like it happened at Question 1?

Answer (score 8):

*1. The klass object is instance of MyClass.*

No it is a reference variable of type `MyClass` but referring to an object of `MyClass2.`

*2. Why does it execute the method from the MyClass2 class?*

Since you are invoking `say()` on an object of `MyClass2`, it executes the `say()` of `MyClass2`. Expected behavior.

This is called the **run time polymorphism** in Java. This provides the ability to override functionality already available in the class hierarchy tree. At run time, which version of the method will be invoked is based on the type of actual object stored in that reference variable and not on the type of the reference variable.

*3. At question 1 klass calls the method of the Class2 class. Here I used a parameter that fits to each one of the overridden and overloaded (simultaneously) methods. Why klass object always calls the method from the MyClass class?*

That is not overridden method. An instance method in a subclass with the **same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters)** and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method. This is called a covariant return type.Your method signatures are different. Hence invoking `klass.print()` where `klass` is a `MyClass` reference will always refer to the `print()` of `MyClass`.

*4. It is right to throw an exception. The klass object does not have this method with double parameter. But, why it is not called the method from the MyClass2 class, just like it happened at Question 1?*

Because at compile time, the compiler validates if you can call a method based on the reference type. Here the reference type is `MyClass` and since `MyClass` doesn't define `anotherPrint(double)`, the compiler complains.It is a compile time check.In question 1, compiler verified `klass.say("hi")` and it saw that there exists a method in `MyClass` which can be invoked this way. At that time, it was not concerned whether `klass` reference variable will refer to a `MyClass` object or `MyClass2` object at runtime. Hence it worked.

You can refer to these Oracle's tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Answer (score 2):

An instance of a class will have the methods of the father(s) plus its own methods. If the signature of one of the child class is the same than the signature of a method in the father, will override it.

In this example, an instance of MyClass2 will have this methods:

```
public void say(String t) //From MyClass2 (override)
public void print(MyClass2 t)
public void anotherPrint(double i)
public void print(MyClass t) //Inherited from MyClass
public void anotherPrint(int i) //Inherited from MyClass
```

But you are declaring klass as a MyClass, so it will have available this methods

```
public void say(String t) //From MyClass
public void print(MyClass t)
public void anotherPrint(int i)
```

Now, answering your questions

1 - You invoke the method say of a MyClass. But in runtime, actually klass is an object of MyClass2 and MyClass2 overrides this method, so it will invoke the one from MyClass2

2,3 - You invoke the method print of MyClass. In runtime, klass is from MyClass2, but MyClass2 IS NOT OVERRIDING THIS METHOD. The signature is different. So the one to be called is the MyClass. Works fine with a MyClass2 object as parameter since MyClass2 is a MyClass

5 - MyClass has not any method called anotherPrint receiving a double

Comment: Finally, I believe that, I understood when the overridden method is getting called or not. But I believe that the method with the parameter "MyClass2" fullfills the requirements and this method should be called instead of the other. Could you be more specific at this explanation?

Comment: @LiTTle It´s because the variable klass is declared as MyClass, so the only methods available are the ones i posted in the second block of code. There is no method receiving a MyClass2 instance. Since MyClass2 is a class that extends MyClass, print(MyClass t) can be called with any instance of MyClass or their subclasses, but will call print(MyClass t). Look that Myclass2 has two methods print(one takes MyClass, other takes MyClass2). Check the case asked in question 5. Trying to call anotherPrint with a double does not work, MyClass´s anotherPrint takes an int, not a double.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:-  With the line MyClass klass = new MyClass2(); you have done upcasting, catching the reference id(object) of child class. In case of upcasting, the methods of the child class are called.
Though the compiler checks for the say() function in the parent at comiple time but at run time compiler sees that we have say() function in child also, so it binds it with the child class method and calls it. This is the reason you are getting the output for Question 1 as Hello MyClass2 h

Answer (score 0):

Method overloading and method overriding in Java is two important concept in Java which allows Java programmer to declare method with same name but different behavior. Method overloading and method overriding is based on polymorphism in Java. In case of method overloading, method with same name co-exists in same class but they must have different method signature, while in case of method overriding, method with same name is declared in derived class or sub class.Method overloading is resolved using static binding in Java at compile time while method overriding is resolved using dynamic binding in Java at runtime. In short When you overload a method in Java its method signature got changed while in case of overriding method signature remains same but a method can only be overridden in sub class. Since Java supports polymorphism and resolve object at run-time it is capable to call overridden method in Java

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/method-overloading-vs-method-overriding.html#ixzz34EEhLp2u